# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft.office.interop.excel

I have a console app and trying to read Excel file, by using the library: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

I get below error:

```
 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

the error comes from: **Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();**

Comment: Yes, office.dll is another interop assembly that is needed to interop with Excel.  It will always be part of the project's references once you add the dependency.  You perhaps did this in an unusual way, using a Nuget package is a bad idea.  Or forgot to copy it to the target machine that fails with this exception.